# How can I place a bounty on someone else's question?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I'm trying to place a bounty on a question in SO, but I don't see the option to do this.  I thought a question had to be at least 24 hours old, but [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353291/minimum-and-maximum-value-for-uiaccelerationvalue) is from 11/12, so it's at least a day old (possibly 2).

Comment: Not 24 hours, 48 hours.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: The FAQ I linked does, and so does the the main [FAQ]. -- *"A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked."*

Comment: @animuson Ah, I was betrayed by the search functionality (I looked for hours). It's rather strange that some of it is in hours and some of it is in days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place a bounty until the question is **two days old**. That one is *almost* 2 days old.

Timestamp: `2012-11-12 23:24:07Z`

Current UTC time: `2012-11-14 18:23`

So you still have approximately 5 hours to go before it's bounty-eligible.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the post, there will be the text

`start a bounty`

but it will only be on questions that are a certain number of days old.  I think the threshold is 2 days.

I believe if it's your own question, It will tell you when it becomes bounty eligible